# Add more than current iteration to your queries view (TFS 2018)

Tags: tfs

[image]

Anybody who knows if it possible to configure the queries view to show more than the current iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it possible. You can do next:

1. Create new folder for queries.

[image]

[image]

2. Edit existing query.

[image]

3. Save that query to new destination.

[image]

[image]

4. Also you can use [Group clauses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/using-queries#group-clauses)

[image]

Additional information you can find here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/using-queries